# Getting values OF a set in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, counter, multiple-conditions

I have 6 arrays, let's say `a,b,c1,d1,c2,d2`.

Arrays `a and b` have some common pairs of `c1,c2` and `d1,d2`. I find these common pairs, **i.e. those `a and b` which have the same `c1,d1` and `c2,d2` like this:**

```
data_zcosmo_lastz = a
data_zphot_lastz = b
halo_id_zcosmo = c1 
halo_id_zphot = c2
idrep_zcosmo = d1
idrep_zphot = d2


file2freq1 = Counter(zip(c1,d1))
file2freq2 = Counter(zip(c2,d2))

set_a = set(file2freq1) & set(file2freq2) # common objects
```

The above code gives `set_a` to have those common values of `c1,d1` and `c2,d2`.

**But how do I get the values of `a and b` of `set_a`?**

**i.e. I want the `a` and `b` values of `set_a`.**

Example

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
c1 = [1,1,1,2,2]
d1 = [3,3,3,4,4]
c2 = [1,1,2,2,2]
d2 = [3,3,1,4,4]

so set_a = [(1,3),(1,3),(2,4),(2,4)]
```

Now I want those values of `a and b` that have these pairs. i.e.

```
a = [1,2,4,5] and b = [2,3,5,6]
```

Comment: "But how do I get the values of a and b of set_a?" What do you mean? The indices? Could you show a minimal example for the input arrays and what you want to get in the end?

Comment: @tobias_k: Have edited the question with an example. I hope it makes it simpler to understand. I want not just the indices, but the values of `a` and `b` that belong to this `set_a`

Comment: Do the matching pairs of c1/d1 and c2/d2 have to line up, as they do in your example? Using `set` and `Counter`, you lose this information.

Comment: Actually I just realised that.. But I would like to get them in order and also as stated in the example. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want the elements of `a` and `b` at those positions where the elements of `c1` and `d1` are the same as those of `c2` and `d2` respectively.

In this case, using `set` and `Counter` won't help, as those will erase any information on the position. Instead, just `zip` all those lists together...

```
for a_, b_, c1_, d1_, c2_, d2_ in zip(a,b,c1,d1,c2,d2):
    if (c1_,d1_) == (c2_,d2_):
        print(a_, b_)
```

... or just `zip` the `c1,d1,c2,d2` lists and use `enumerate` to get the positions:

```
idx = [i for i, t in enumerate(zip(c1,d1,c2,d2)) if t[:2] == t[2:]]
print([(a[i], b[i]) for i in idx])
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use `numpy` for this, after converting your arrays to `numpy.arrays` doing e.g. `A = np.array(a)` and so on.

```
>>> match = np.logical_and(C1 == C2, D1 == D2)
>>> match
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> A[match]
array([1, 2, 4, 5])
>>> B[match]
array([2, 3, 5, 6])
```